# Filling out a user form with data from a spreadsheet after selecting one criteria

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm a complete novice with VBA but I managed to import the web data and also create a user form.

I'm trying to make a user form to list a set of used vehicles and their respective information.

So far, I got it so it displays the list of vehicles, but I'm wondering as to how a button click for the list of vehicles will allow me to fill out the rest of the text boxes (shown in the screenshots below).

I have named the ranges as well.

Thanks!

[Album with data, user form and code](http://imgur.com/a/K053C)

My thought process: I'm thinking of using an array to fill out the information and have the user form display the information accordingly. But I feel like that's not really necessary from the googling that I have done, but can't seem to find a solution either.

Answer (score 0):

I think if i am correct you want to save data after taking input. If thats correct you ca use msgbox option and take feeds and save in excel ,etc. If i am wrong please correct me.